# The type <type> exists in both DLLs. Reloading a dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen many questions similar to this, but they all seem to have the problem originating in differences of version or target framework, the problem I have currently is based on rebuilding the same dll with the same version and replacing the runtime with MEF.
Complete sample available [here](https://github.com/Andrea/TempMEF) (shadow copy is enabled)

The problem is as follows:

- Host application loads dll from a plugins folder
- Change something about the dll and recompile
- debug into the dll
- in the immediate window try to debug anything about a type contained in the dll (ie do typeof(Bar) in inmediate window)

then you get this exception.
Any ideas? I m trying to understand the source of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to use multiple `AppDomains`.

You can't load two assemblies that have the same name.  So you will have to unload the original.  However, you can't unload an assembly!

You can unload an `AppDomain`.  So you will load everything you need into a new `AppDomain` and then unload it when you want unload the assembly.

Comment: can you comment on the reason for this, I would like to understand

Comment: @Miau there are various articles out there on how to create and communicated between different app domains.

Comment: Probably the solution will end up being something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633140/MEF-and-AppDomain-Remove-Assemblies-On-The-Fly

Comment: Just FYI: By default, .NET uses remoting to pass information between different AppDomains.